# Calling json object dot notation with a variable

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a json object to access the path is
`data.Application.Exabeam`

```
const target = data.Application.Exabeam
```

I have trouble , I would like to replace the "Exabeam" to be referenced by a variable

I tried to add a variable as follows

```
var casetypesession = sessionStorage.getItem("homepageclicksession");
```

a) `const target = data.Application.casetypesession;` (dosn't work because there is no `casetypesession` in my json object

b) `const target=data.Applications.casetypesession.valueOf();` (dosn't work, `casetypesession` is not even recognized in the variable in the dot notation)

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for accessing the property of an object is:

```
objectName.property         // person.age
```

or

```
objectName["property"]      // person["age"]
```

or

```
objectName[expression]      // x = "age"; person[x]
```

See [this reference](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp) for details.

Which in your case translates to something like this:

```
const target = data.Applications[casetypesession]
```

Comment: Hi i am not accessing the property of the object .

im trying to get the all objects within the Exabeam portion. 


{


    "Applications":[

      {

        "Exabeam" : [

          { 

            "Category" : {

Comment: @sherrez I've updated the answer with your example

Comment: @sherrez Please provide the value of __casetypesession__ and __data.Applications__ then in original post

Comment: Hi peter i got it to work , sorry my own mistake 

i didnt specify the array before that .

const target=data.Applications[0][casetypesession];

thank you so much for your help appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

My own mistake, did not specify the array before the exabeam portion!

target=data.Applications[0][casetypesession];